# Powershell script runtime error when clicking navigate/export excel button in showlistview result

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am using Powershell to generate a report using `show-listview` but sometimes when the user clicks the excel report or navigation button in the result window it's showing a runtime error.

I have verified the logs:

```
ManagedPoolThread #6 10:03:03 INFO The script execution in ScriptSession '$scriptSession$|p5tximzzm0ag34m2wvixqfvz|276a0a8b-f56f-46ec-bc78-46d60f1385c4' completed in 845 ms.
5360 10:03:04 INFO 'GET/handle' called by user: ''
96 10:03:32 INFO Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')     
96 10:03:32 INFO Executing PsSitecoreItemProvider.Start(providerInfo='Sitecore')
```

I have tried with different browsers and private windows but still, I am getting the error.  I have verified the user role - it has the permission

Any suggestion to avoid the error. Thanks!!

the below is the code I am using

```powershell
function Get-ItemUrl($website,$itemToProcess,$itemLng){
     $site = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext]::GetSite($website)
        $urlOptions = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetDefaultUrlOptions()
        $urlOptions.Language = $itemLng
    $urlOptions.Site=$site 
        $url = [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($itemToProcess, $urlOptions)
        return "http"+$url
    }
$options = @{
    "site1"="en"
    "site2"="en"}
$props = @{
    Parameters = @(
        @{Name="selectedOption"; Title="Select the Site"; Options=$options;}
    )}
$selectedSite = Read-Variable @props
$PageBaseTemplateItem= "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}";
$pathNode = 'master://sitecore/content/Home
$allItems=@()
        $homeItem = Get-Item -Path $pathNode -Language *
        $allItems += $homeItem
        $allItems += Get-ChildItem -Path $pathNode -Recurse -Language * | Where-Object { $PageBaseTemplateItem -in $_.Template.BaseTemplates.ID}
$allItems  | Show-ListView -Property `
   @{ Name="Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},   
   @{ Name="Path"; Expression={$_.FullPath}},   
   @{ Name="URL"; Expression={Get-ItemURL -website $selectedOption -itemToProcess $_ -itemLng $_.Language}}
```

I am getting the below error msg:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Controls.PowerShellListView.get_FilteredItems() +1137
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellResultViewerList.SetVariables(ScriptSession session, Message message) +112
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellResultViewerList.ExecuteScriptJob(Item scriptItem, ScriptSession scriptSession, Message message, Boolean autoDispose) +249
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellResultViewerList.ExportResults(Message message) +345
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Client.Applications.PowerShellResultViewerList.HandleMessage(Message message) +1352
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +152
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +547
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

Comment: What versions are you running?

Comment: You might want to add information about the error (and if possible about the script). And "sometimes" always sounds fishy.. - any logic or just random?

Comment: I am using Sitecore Powershell module 5.0

Comment: Hi Michael - I using Powershell module 5.0

Comment: Hi Gatogordo,  I have placed my code with the question

Comment: What does the runtime error look like?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have updated the error message with the question - can you please have 
 a look

Comment: Hi Gatogordo, I have added the error message - can you please have a look

Comment: I'm having the same error.
Did you find a solution for this? Thanks!